# How to express this axiom in first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Reading in a book on logic I found some examples of structures and languages in first order logic:

The language $L_{geom}$ of basic plane geometry has two 1-place relation symbols $P$
and $L$ for “point” and “line”, and a 2-place relation symbol $I$ for “point $x$ lies on
line $y$”. Examples of axioms are:

- $\forall x(P(x) ∨ L(x))$
- $\forall x¬(P (x) ∧ L(x))$

these axioms mean: everything is either a point or a line; and
not both.

how to express this axiom in $L_{geom}$: for every two points there is a unique line they lie on.

Answer (score 3):

$\forall x,y (P(x) \land P(y) \implies \exists z ( L(z) \land I(x,z) \land I(y,z)))$

is the part of the axiom concerning the existence of a line that joins every two points. I’ll let you figure out how to formalize the uniqueness of that line (Hint: what must happen if we pick two lines joining the same pair of points?)

Comment: Yes, if we have two lines that pass through the same points, they must be the same.